# umbraco 7 can't take tab names from dictionary using #key

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, multilingual, umbraco7

I'm using umbraco 7 for a project and trying to make the umbraco take the tab names from the dictionary. I've tried using #key for the name but that doesn't seem to be working, any ideas?

it displays as #products on the tab name instead of the translation

Answer (score 0):

Tab names will be translated on content pages, not in document type settings (this is where they are defined).
https://our.umbraco.com/forum/extending-umbraco-and-using-the-api/80696-how-to-localize-umbraco-backend-document-types